# git pull --rebase - how to proceed after conflict resolution

Tags: git

I'm doing `git pull --rebase` and get a conflict. After I resolve a conflict, git show me that I'm in the middle of a merge. If I was doing a simple merge, I'd just add resolved files to the index and do a manual commit. But since I'm also rebasing how do I proceed to have other commits applied after I've resolved a conflict?

Comment: Try `git merge --continue`

Comment: [git merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) doesn't seem to have such option

Comment: I think it would be more of a `git rebase --continue` cause it's a rebase

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes, you're right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you used `git pull --rebase` and got conflicts, git displayed :

> When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
>
> If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
>
> To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

In your case, you should use `git rebase --continue`